# Installing Cygwin C and C++ compilers for NetBeans IDE 7.2

Tags: cygwin, netbeans, compile, c++, c

I am very new to Cygwin, C, C++ and NetBeans IDE 7.2. My PC is running MICROSOFT WINDOWS 7 OS.

I have read the documentation on how to install the Cygwin C C++ compilers.

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers

I have tried to run Cygwin setup.exe that has the most recent version of the Cygwin DLL is 1.7.16-1.

I am not very sure which exact package to install when the Cygwin setup.exe installer prompted for the selection of packages to download and install. I want to install the Cygwin C and C++ compilers so that i can create C and C++ projects using NetBeans 7.2

I selected those packages that has contains the following names
gcc, g++, gdb and make. Then i proceed on to install the selected packages

The installation took up a long time so i stopped after about 45 minutes or so.

I browsed the installation folder and i saw some packages i selected were installed. I noticed that some packages came in some sort of "zip" file with tar.gz extension.

i added the folder path into the PATH variable in the windows 7 environment variables window.

I think this command works

C:> cygcheck -c cygwin

but the rest doesn't work i think.

C:> gcc --version

C:> g++ --version

C:> make --version

C:> gdb --version

I tried to create the C C++ project using the Netbeans IDE 7.2 and the IDE pops out a dialog message saying that there was no c c++ compilers found.

Have i made some mistake here? like installing the wrong packages or something else???

Are there packages shown in the Cygwin setup.exe installer that contains exact names and exact version that is compatible with NetBeans IDE 7.2?? This i am not too sure. Because i i think i didn't really see some required packages with exact names and versions.

My question is : Which exact packages do i install using the Cygwin setup.exe installer so that i can create C & C++ projects using Netbeans IDE 7.2? and what other steps do i have to take note to ensure complete successful installation? do i have to wait all the selected required packages to be installed?

I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW THE EXACT NAMES AND THE VERSIONS FOR THE REQUIRED PACKAGES (NAMES AND VERSIONS DISPLAYED IN THE CYGWIN SETUP.EXE INSTALLER WHEN PROMPTED) NEEEDED FOR C & C++ PROGRAMMING USING NETBEANS IDE 7.2??

Comment: The packages you list should be enough. Don't interrupt the installation procedure.

Comment: I interupted the installation procedure because i really cannot wait for the installation to finish that time. By the way, Which exact packages do i install using the Cygwin setup.exe installer so that i can create C C++ projects using Netbeans IDE 7.2? What are the exact names and versions of the required packages?

Comment: The most reason versions work fine. As I said, your list of packages is OK. The list is: g++, gcc, gdb, make. Also, you can wait for the installation to finish. Let your computer do it overnight.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2012-08-21, you should make sure you install these package versions:

- cygwin1.dll   1.7.7, 1.7.9    Cygwin Linux-like environment for Windows
- gcc   4.3.4   Cygwin C compiler
- g++   4.3.4   Cygwin C++ compiler
- gdb   6.8     Cygwin GNU debugger
- make  3.81    Cygwin make utility

IDE 7.2 is tested with these above versions only, so if your compilers are not of same versions you will probably get an error.